# Change user name associated with Apple Mouse 1

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I bought a used iMac that included an Apple Mouse 1. In the Bluetooth settings, under System Preferences, it lists the previous owner's name.

Even if I use that same mouse on my MBP, the old user's name still displays in the MBP Bluetooth settings.

Is there a way to delete or change a name embedded in the mouse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the mouse so it's active.  Then Open System Preferences >> Bluetooth, and right-click the entry in the list of devices.  Choose "Rename".